# Python - Simple for loop not working as expected (with requests module)

Tags: python, api, for-loop, python-requests, append

I must be missing something here since the computer doesn't joke around but this simple for loop is seemingly not giving me the desired output. Below is the code which uses [aztro's API](https://aztro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to grab today's horoscope for each of 12 zodiac signs and put them all in a list.

```
import requests
import json

zodiacSigns = ['Aries', 'Taurus', 'Gemini', 'Cancer', 'Leo', 'Virgo', 'Libra', 'Scorpio', 'Sagittarius', 'Capricorn', 'Aquarius', 'Pisces']

for zodiacSign in zodiacSigns:
    params = (('sign','{}'.format(zodiacSign)), ('day','today'))
    output = json.loads(requests.post('https://aztro.sameerkumar.website/', params=params).text)
    descriptions = []
    descriptions.append(output['description'])

print(descriptions)
```

This code outputs the horoscope for only Pisces, the last element in the list above:

```
["You need to take work more seriously today -- it may be that you've got an opportunity coming up that shouldn't be missed. It's easier than usual for you to make career moves, so go for it!"]
```

As a reference, a sample output of this aztro's API for a single zodiac sign is:

```
{
   "compatibility":" Virgo",
   "date_range":"Jan 20 - Feb 18",
   "current_date":"August 23, 2018",
   "description":"Today requires a willingness to go deeper than usual -- maybe to explore the nuances of your primary relationship, maybe to really get to know that one client or maybe just reading between the lines.",
   "lucky_time":" 10am",
   "lucky_number":" 13",
   "color":" Navy Blue",
   "mood":" Thoughtful"
}
```

The desired output would be a list of horoscopes for all 12 zodiac signs. I can't seem to catch the issue here, so I'd appreciate input from more experienced eyes. Gracias!

Comment: You define descriptions as an empty list in each iteration. Move that definition to before the loop.

Comment: In addition, you don't need `json.loads()` because requests response object has a `.json()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the declaration of the `descriptions` variable, which at every iteration is initialized to be an empty list.

Just move it out from the loop, like so:

```
descriptions = []
for zodiacSign in zodiacSigns:
    params = (('sign','{}'.format(zodiacSign)), ('day','today'))
    output = json.loads(requests.post('https://aztro.sameerkumar.website/', params=params).text)
    descriptions.append(output['description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `descriptions = []` should be out of the for loop. If it is in the for loop, it will be initiated (erased, in this case) every iteration.

The code below should work:

```
import requests
import json

zodiacSigns = ['Aries', 'Taurus', 'Gemini', 'Cancer', 'Leo', 'Virgo', 'Libra', 'Scorpio', 'Sagittarius', 'Capricorn', 'Aquarius', 'Pisces']

descriptions = []

for zodiacSign in zodiacSigns:
    params = (('sign','{}'.format(zodiacSign)), ('day','today'))
    output = json.loads(requests.post('https://aztro.sameerkumar.website/', params=params).text)
    descriptions.append(output['description'])

print(descriptions)
```